# Is there a Java formatting library for user input?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dto

This seems like it would be a really common thing to need in just about any Java project.  And yet I am unable to find anything that serves this purpose.

I used to use a web framework called Stripes Framework, that had annotation driven validators and automatic formatting via their validator API.

**Example:**

```
@Validate(maxlength = ModelConstants.NAME_MAX_LENGTH, converter = CapitializeFullyTypeConverter.class)
private String name;

@Validate(maxlength = ModelConstants.NAME_MAX_LENGTH, converter = EmailTypeConverter.class)
private String email;
```

Those fields would be defined on your controller action bean, and all user input would automatically be validated and formatted according to the specified rules.

If someone would enter their email address as: "TEST@TEST.COM"
Then it would automatically be formatted to: "test@test.com"

I would like to find something like this for automatically formatting data within DTOs.

If nothing like this is available, what is the usual way of handling this?  Surely everyone is not writing custom formatting functions for each getter within the DTO?

Comment: Are you using _Spring Boot_ or _Spring MVC_? Should your _conversions_ only apply from request Strings to DTO Strings, i.e. cleaning during request deserialization? What is user-input: HTTP __request-parameters__ or request-body (e.g. JSON/XML) too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assumption: meaning of "formatter" as [type-converter](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/STRIPES/pages/492136/Validation+Reference#ValidationReference-TypeConversion)

When you ask for *annotation based "formatter"* you mean [Stripe Framework's](https://jaxenter.com/tutorial-stripes-a-lean-mean-java-web-framework-104577.html) `@Validate` annotation with its parameter [`converter`](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/STRIPES/pages/492124/Annotation+Reference#AnnotationReference-@Validate). The *converter* can be parameterized as:

> (class) The converter class that will be used to transform this parameter into its object representation

In the Web-MVC context this means the *converter* is used to convert the request-parameter, exactly its *source value*, as supplied by the incomming web-request. The *converted value* is then stored as *target value* to the  (DTO) object's property.

#### Example: Conversion of (DTO) Strings

Web request is given incommong with parameter name *email* and value string `TEST@EXAMPLE.COM`. This should the be converted to lowercase and strored in the DTO's property (a.k.a attribute or field )  *email* as value `test@example.com`.

#### Spring annotations for DTOs

Spring Framework also uses the concepts of *request **validation*** and *request **conversion***. It also allows to configure these annotations-driven on the DTOs or classes and their attributes.

The **validation** leverages Java Bean Validation standard (JSR-303) [`javax.validation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/package-summary.html) annotations like `@Valid` and `@Length`.

The **conversion** is part of the *HttpConverters* used for serialization/deserialization of responses/requests to/from objects (DTO). Therefore Spring allows to inlude *object-relational mapper* (ORM) frameworks or libraries as (e.g. Maven) dependencies. These bring their own annotations regarding conversation with them.

#### Fasterxml's Jackson

Jackson (ORM) for example uses the annotation [`@JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) to achieve simple string conversions - but only for non-string fields like *Date* or *Number* (as far as I know).
It also allows complete customisation of serializers and deserializers via annotations `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize`.
Note, that although many annotations in Jackson are named with "Json" they mostly also apply to XML or even other data formats (representations) like CSV, etc.

#### String To Lowercase with Jackson

Your question was asked for Jackson: [How to force Jackson deserialize field values to lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845569/how-to-force-jackson-deserialize-field-values-to-lower-case) and answered.

#### See also

- [Difference between @Valid and @Validated in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring)
- [Use Jackson to deserialize JSON string or object into a String field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740026/ddg#42740192)
- DZone: [Tutorial on Jackson Deserialization Annotations](https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-annotations-for-json-part-3-deserialization)
- Bealdung (2019): [Getting Started with Custom Deserialization in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Comment: You are correct, in that I am ultimately referring to  "type conversion".  Guess I was using the wrong terminology.  Thank you for your answer.  It seems creating custom Jackson deserializers might be the way to go, although I have already moved past this, and ended up just formatting the input via the setters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Mvc, you have access to a formatting API. 
There are pre-existing annotations in the `org.springframework.format.annotation` package for date and number formatting.

If you need custom formatting rules, you can write your own and register it via the `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`.

See some examples here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RC1/reference/html/validation.html

Comment: Thank you.  This isn't exactly what I was after, but it doesn't look like what I am looking for exists.  The Spring solution is pretty heavy weight, and not as easy as just defining annotation based type converters at the field level, which is more what I was looking for.